# Truncate trailing zeroes regex

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

How to get a match using regex to truncate zeroes in a string like this

```
45.9390 => 45.939
32.00 => 32.0 [Need this for my use case]
32.0050 => 32.005
32 => 32
```

I am using Java. I am just looking for the regex. This is my closest attempt( https://regex101.com/r/mD7gK4/79 ). I am missing on the second case.

Comment: Maybe [`(?<=\d)0$`](https://regex101.com/r/ZM2xFV/1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your regex:

```
^([+-]?\d*\.0)0+$|^([+-]?\d*\.?\d*?)0*$
```

and use `\1\2` as substitution string:

**Demo**: https://regex101.com/r/mD7gK4/81

**Output**:

```
45.9390 => 45.939
32.00 => 32.0
32.0050 => 32.005
32 => 32
```