# ios_base::fixed & truncating trailing zeroes

Tags: c++, ibm-midrange

When printing certain decimal numbers, rounding may occur (my present platform is the IBM iSeries).  If I set ios_base::fixed, it does better but prints annoying trailing (and insignificant) zeroes.  Anyone have a better way?  For the platform I'm using, the output is this:

> ```
> myval=100000
> myval=99999.990000
> myval as string =99999.990000
> ```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// returns t
template<typename T> string toString(const T& val)
{
    stringstream os;

    os.setf(std::ios_base::fixed);
    os << val;
    return os.str();
}

class MyApp {
private :
public :
    MyApp();
    virtual ~MyApp();

    void run();

    operator bool() const { return true; }
};


MyApp::MyApp()
{
}

MyApp::~MyApp()
{
}

void MyApp::run()
{
    double myval = 99999.99;
    string myval_as_string = toString<double>(myval);

    cout << "myval=" << myval << endl;

    cout.setf(std::ios_base::fixed);

    cout << "myval=" << myval << endl;
    cout << "myval as string =" << myval_as_string << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyApp myApp;

    myApp.run();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunetly C++ makes this really hard to do.  Most approaches I've seen involve converting to a string and then erasing the trailing zeros from the string.  Maybe C++17's [`to_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars) will make this easier.

Comment: I may adapt what I found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48981702/truncate-trailing-zeroes-regex

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `precision` and not `fixed`.  `precision` will specify the maximum precision used but it will not automatically print more zeros so increase it as much as you need.  `fixed` will force it out to as many zeros as `precision` is set to.  If you have set `fixed` previously, you can reset it with `ios_base::defaultfloat`.

```
template<typename T> string toString(const T& val)
{
    stringstream os;

    os.precision(15);
    os << val;
    return os.str();
}
....
void MyApp::run()
{
    double myval = 99999.99;
    string myval_as_string = toString<double>(myval);

    cout << "myval=" << myval << endl;
    cout.precision(15);
    cout << "myval=" << myval << endl;
    cout << "myval as string =" << myval_as_string << endl;
}
```

For more info, you can check out the standard here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/.  Note the following line:

> Using the default floating-point notation, the precision field
>   specifies the maximum number of meaningful digits to display in total
>   counting both those before and those after the decimal point. Notice
>   that it is not a minimum, and therefore it does not pad the displayed
>   number with trailing zeros if the number can be displayed with less
>   digits than the precision.